# Smooth Caret Animation in the Atom Editor

Tags: css, less, atom-editor

When a smooth caret animation in the atom editor is added, the background starts blinking uncontrollably.

This is the code I use to add the animation in my style.less

```
atom-text-editor .cursor {
    transition: all 80ms;
}
```

Here's a gif of what happens -
[image: Blink Animation]

**What CSS can I use to prevent this?**

### Update:

Turns out this was a ubuntu 18.04 specific issue. Check the answer for a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Settings -> Core -> Use sRGB color profile

This looks like an issue with rendering, not CSS. The above should at least fix those rectangle outlines, and may fix the blinking too.